# Wpf styles: styling a label in a listbox

Tags: wpf

Is there a way to define a style that is applied to an object only in certain cases?

For example: A style for labels that are part of an item template in a listbox.

I know you can create a key for a style and specify what style to apply to the label directly, but is there another more generic way?

Comment: Haven't tried it, but you might be able to create a DataTrigger in the item's DataTemplate.Triggers that Sets Style to a particular resource.  I'm not sure if data trigger Setter elements will resolve resources or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to define the style at the lowest level in the hierarchy where it becomes relevant and set the `TargetType` of the style without a key.

This will force the style to apply to the defined type down the hierarchy relative to its definition.

In this instance the resource would live within the `ListBox` and thus get applied to your template.

```
<ListBox.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Label"/>
</ListBox.Resources>
```